# Average Distances From The Origin

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

> Consider all points $(m,n)$ where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers,
>   $m\leq10$, and $n\leq5$. What is the average distances from each point
>   to the origin $(0,0)$?

I know how to find the distance $d$ between the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$;
$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$.

In this case, the first point is $(m,n)$ and the second point is the origin, therefore the distance, $d=\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$.

It is annoying to find all distances, summing them, and dividing them by the number of distances, is not it annoying?

What if the given conditions, $m\leq10$ and $n\leq5$, were changed to $m\leq49$ and $n\leq36$?!

Comment: I don't think there's a quick way, It's easy with a computer program. For very large $m$ and $n$ you could get an approximation using calculus.

Comment: Even with small values of $m$ and $n$, it is annoying. Say $m\leq5$, and $n\leq2$. You will calculate $10$ distances. As you said it is easy by programming, but without that, can not we? :(

Answer (score -1):

There is a quick solution for a related problem, even though it's not quite what you are asking. If you are willing to compute *squares* of distances of all points, then you get
$$
\begin{split}
f(m,n)
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n \left(i^2 + k^2\right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \\
 &= n \sum_{i=1}^m i^2 + m \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \\
 &= n \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6} + m \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
 &= \frac{mn}{6} \left[(m+1)(2m+1) + (n+1)(2n+1)\right]
\end{split}
$$

As expected, $f(m,n)$ is symmetric in $m,n$, in other words, $f(m,n) = f(n,m)$...

Comment: This is not related. However, it is new for me, I like it.
But should not it be $f(m-1,n-1)$ since $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers (non-zero positive integers)?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari do you mean you want to include $0$? It is easy to change the above to accommodate for that if you like

Comment: What you have posted (including $0$). My problem (excluding $0$ because they are natural numbers). So, should it be $f(m-1,n-1)$?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I don't understand. My post does **not** include zero, since both sums start with min index $1$, so the points $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)$ are included but $(0,x),(x,0)$ are not included

Comment: Yes, you are right. What about my original problem? No way? :(

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I think your only hope is to square the sum and hope you can do something with the cross terms... roots don't usually sum that easily. What do you need this for?